# IntelliJ IDEA warns about Scala imports instead of showing type info when importing object members

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have code similar to below

```
import sqlCtx.implicits._
val items = sc.parallelize(List(i1, i2, i3))
items.toDF().registerTempTable("items")
```

When I hover over `items` I would like usual behaviour - displaying type information. Instead I get warnings `Avoid wildcard imports` and `Imports should be grouped together`. I can get rid of the first by importing specific function, like

```
import sqlCtx.implicits.rddToDataFrameHolder
```

but I can't put import on top of the file what IntelliJ expects of me since it imports from an object that is created with the code and not preexisting. How to workaround it?

I use IntelliJ IDEA v. 15.0.3 with the latest Scala plugin.

Comment: If the function you're looking for doesn't exist at compile time, the import probably won't work, and you'll have to get it via reflection at runtime.  I'm not sure though, that's just my initial guess.

Comment: It's not about function existing or not, code works fine. It's about IDE's annoying behaviour.